# Survey score. Find the percentage

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a `xlsx` document with some score values and I have imported them with `pandas` to Python. There are numbers from 0-10 (from worst to best) based on customers' experience with a store. My goal is to find out how many customers answered 0-6 and the percentage. Many of the rows in that column are empty (because many customers didn't answer), so is it best to use `dropna` to get rid of the empty ones? And how can I find out how many customers answered 0-6? I used this code below to find out how many answered 0, but is there a faster/better way to do this?

`(np.count_nonzero(score == 0))`

[image: Score]

Comment: probably best to just get all the score cells values, then do the filtering in pure Python, like you just had a list of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I would use dropna to remove the roes with missing values. Then I would just simply use df.score(name of the column).value_counts().sort_index() in order to get the frequency for each number.

```
df.dropna(axis = 0, inplace = True)
clean_df = df.score.value_counts().sort_index()
print(clean_df)
```